# Continued increments in Emmet?

Tags: emmet

When I input the following:

> ul*3>li{Item $}*5

I will get the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Is it at all possible to get the following result using a similiar input?

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
</ul>
```

From the docs, it seems it's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not as concise as you'd like, but this works:

```
ul>li{item $}*5^ul>li{item $@6}*5^ul>li{item $@11}*5
```